# WebPack dependency cannot be resolved in generated js with __webpack_require__ syntax

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, websocket

### TL;DR

- I'm using `ts-loader` for compiling TypeScript => JavaScript
- I have a dependency `const WebSocket = require('ws');` in my uncompiled typescript code
- It gets compiled into `var WebSocket = __webpack_require__(333);` in my js output file
- This causes errors!
- If I manually revert `var WebSocket = __webpack_require__(333);` => `const WebSocket = require('ws');` in the generated js file, the error can be avoided.

Therefore, my question is:

**=> Can I "force" webpack to compile the dependency `const WebSocket = require('ws');` => `const WebSocket = require('ws');` (no changes)?**

If there is any other way to enforce this dependency in the generated file, I'm happy to hear other suggestions as well of course.

### Long story & background info

I'm trying to setup an angular 6 universal ssr (server-side rendering) scenario with websockets. I use webpack to compile the nodejs webserver from typescript => javascript. I keep getting an error "ReferenceError: WebSocket is not defined". After 2 weeks of troubleshooting, I finally figured out, that nodejs doesn't have native websocket support (browser has). So after adding `"ws": "^6.0.0"` to my package.json and importing it  (`const WebSocket = require('ws');`) into my webpack-compiled js file, I finally got it to work! *However,* if I import it into the uncompiled ts file, it will be compiled into `var WebSocket = __webpack_require__(333);` which doesn't work.

### Apologies & Disclaimer

I also opened issues in the respective repos (https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/1042 & https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3942), but nobody was able to help me. My question might be misleading, due to my very limited understanding of how webpack works. If this should be the case, I'm deeply sorry.